# How to configure bandwidth throttling for all FTP?

Tags: tc

I configured bandwidth throttling for ftp by using following commands

```
sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 1
sudo /sbin/tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 5kbps ceil 9kbps prio 0
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 20 0xffff flowid 1:1
```

then i checked with wget command by downloading a file from internet. But the download speed is not changing i.e. not limiting under the 9kbps. What should i do?.I have to configure delay also? if yes, how much? Thanks.